# getting google map to appear in a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a very simple web site with a set of div's comprising banner(full width), left menu(200px) and right content(600px). I have five menu items which use a simple jquery script to load the right hand side content when clicked. Everything works well except for google maps which won't open. when I goto localhost/contact.html it loads fine so the functionality is there. it just doesn't like being embedded in the overall document/html.

Code for the Menu:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#about").on("click", function() {
        $("#content").load("about-us.html");
    });
    $("#candidate").on("click", function() {
        $("#content").load("candidate.html");
    });
    $("#client").on("click", function() {
        $("#content").load("client.html");
    });
    $("#meet").on("click", function() {
        $("#content").load("meet.html");
    });
    $("#contact").on("click", function() {
        $("#content").load("contact.html");
    });
});
```

Code for contact.html

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
        var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.510252,-0.086585);

            function initialize()
            {
                var mapProp = {
                    center: myCenter,
                    zoom: 15,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myCenter,
                    animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
                });

                marker.setMap(map);
            }
    </script>

       <table border="3px">
            <tr><td align="right">
                    t: <br>
                    1st Floor<br>
                    Regis House<br>
                    45 King William Street<br>
                London, EC4R 9AN
                </td>
                <td id="googleMap" width="300px" height="300px">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script type="text/javascript">initialize('googleMap');</script>
</body>
```

Just sniffed with chrome and seeing this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined VM500:1
(anonymous function) VM500:1
o.extend.globalEval jquery-2.1.0.min.js:2
o.fn.extend.domManip jquery-2.1.0.min.js:3
o.fn.extend.append jquery-2.1.0.min.js:3
(anonymous function) jquery-2.1.0.min.js:3
o.access jquery-2.1.0.min.js:2
o.fn.extend.html jquery-2.1.0.min.js:3
(anonymous function) jquery-2.1.0.min.js:4
j jquery-2.1.0.min.js:2
k.fireWith jquery-2.1.0.min.js:2
x jquery-2.1.0.min.js:4
(anonymous function)
```

Comment: You need to add more information to your question.  Here (http://jsfiddle.net/PdcE9/) the Google maps works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a numpty ... this was easy to solve in the end .. given my  is a component of the main  an the simple js is switching out the  I simply needed to put the API call into the main index.html and not the child ... so moved this

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

into the index.html ... all working fine .. now I have a different issue with housing the map within the  when using Firefox ... IE and Chrome fine with the code but Firefox builds the map into the whole page ..